# Getting marginal distributions from a bivariate probability distribution function

Tags: probability, distributions, joint-distribution, bivariate

I understand the basic principles of bivariate distributions and their marginal counterparts. I am stuck on a slightly more sophisticated question however.

Given the following bivariate distribution:

$$
f(x,y) = 
     \begin{cases}
       q &\quad 0 \leq x \leq 1, \ 0 \leq y \leq x\\
       0 &\quad\text{otherwise} \\
     \end{cases}
$$

determine the parameter $q$ and the marginal distributions $f_X(x), f_Y(y)$.

I am aware that the marginal distributions in this case would be:
\begin{align}
f_Y(y) &= \int^{1}_{y} f(x,y)dx  \\[8pt]
f_X(x) &= \int^{x}_{0} f(x,y)dy
\end{align}
But I am not sure how I can go about calculating $q$ to get to that point.

Comment: Hint: the total volume trapped between the $f(x,y)$ surface and the $x$-$y$ plane is $1$. So, $q$ equals the multiplicative inverse of the area of the support of $f(x.y)$.